# HttpClient for calling REST API service is not working

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient, visual-studio-2022, httpresponsemessage

This is the obsolete function - call the function with :

```
string requestData = RestClient.JiraRequest(buildFilter());
```

Function:

```
public static string JiraRequest(string api)
{
    string data = string.Empty;
    
    try
    {
        string requestUrl = @"https://jira.xxxxx.org/rest/api/2/" + api;
        string authType = "Basic";
        string httpMethod = "GET";

        string authHeader = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Config.UserName + ":" + Config.UserPassword));
        _ = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authHeader);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        request.Method = httpMethod;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authType + " " + authHeader);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Exeption error: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleExeption.Exception(ex);
        return data;
    }

    return data;
}
```

This is the new function - call the function with :

```
string requestData = await RestClient.JiraRequest(buildFilter());
```

Function:

```
public static async Task<string> JiraRequest(string api)
{
    string data = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        string requestUrl = @"https://jira.xxxxx.org/rest/api/2/" + api;
        string authType = "Basic";

        using (HttpClient client = new())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authType, Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Config.UserName + ":" + Config.UserPassword)));

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);

            if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("HttClient exception: " + responseMessage.StatusCode.ToString());
            }

            data = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return data;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleExeption.Exception(ex);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Description and history:
with the old code, I got two messages that this approach is obsolete, so I coded the new kind of `HttpClient`.

With the obsolete function, it works perfectly, but with the new function, it doesn't work anymore..

Error in the new function: it crashes after calling

```
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
```

No exception is shown, I have also tried with `Debug.Writeline`, but nothing shows up either.

After calling the this, the program simply exits (crashes)....

Exception(Exception ex):

```
public static void Exception(Exception ex)
        {
            StackTrace stackTrace = new(ex, true);

#nullable enable
            StackFrame? stackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrame(stackTrace.FrameCount - 1);
#nullable disable

            Debug.WriteLine($"Exception message: {ex.Message ?? "No message"}");

            if (stackFrame != null)
            {
                var method = stackFrame.GetMethod();
                Debug.WriteLine($"Exception in method: {method}");

                var lineNumber = stackFrame.GetFileLineNumber();
                Debug.WriteLine($"Exception in line: {lineNumber}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and setting respective breakpoints? Programs typically don't just crash silently, especially if they are compiled in debug mode. What does ` HandleExeption.Exception(ex);` do?

Comment: One thing is of course, the old method is synchronous, the new one is asynchronous. That means, the whole context where you use this method has to be asynchronous. If that isn't the case and you lose your asynchronous context ... So I assume, at least one of the calls in the callstack that lead to this method being called, misses an `await`. And a synchronous `static int Main(...)` won't wait for pending asynchronous operations

Comment: HandleExeption.Exception(ex); does exactly what it should: have updated the comment above.
and is in dubug mode

Comment: no, i only need this call with await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt your program is "crashing" at that particular line of code, because you have exception handling there, which would catch any error thrown in that method.

The only notable difference between the old and the new variant, is that the new one is asynchronous. And somewhere in the callstack that leads to this particular method to be called, you probably don't properly `await` the result of the asynchronous method. Ie you have something like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  ...
  methodA();
}

void methodA() {
  ...
  methodB();
}


async Task methodB() {
  ...
  await methodC();
}

async Task<...> methodC() {
  try {
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    ...

    return ...
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ...
  }
}
```

So when you now call `methodA()` from a synchronous context, it calls `methodB()` without awaiting its result. That's perfectly valid (eventhough it will generate a warning in Visual Studio), but at this point you lose your asynchronous context. This means, that `methodA()` will finish *before*  `methodB()` and this will bubble up the callstack to the `Main()` method, which will also reach its end before `methodB()` is finished.

And when the `Main` method ends, the program terminates. Regardless of whether there are still asynchronous operations pending or not.

This probably happend when you refactored `JiraRequest(string api)` from being synchronous to asynchonous.

You can try to attach a debugger to your program and setting breakpoints

1. directly before `await client.GetAsync(requestUrl)`
2. directly after `await client.GetAsync(requestUrl)`
3. at the very last statement of your `Main` method

I assume your code will hit breakpoints 1 and 3, but not 2. If that's the case, your program isn't crashing but terminating normally, because the callstack is empty.

To resolve that issue, make sure

- all methods in that callstack are `async`
- all async methods are properly `await`ed

Answer (score 0):

a very plausible and understandable explanation. The program does not crash, but has finished working.

Thank you very much, in this case I was looking in the wrong place and did not concentrate on the essential synchronization and asynchronization.

Comment: derpirscher's answer is very helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Comment: @Edlaos You should mark the post as accepted and upvote it instead of thanking it if you think it was useful. If you definitely want to thank, delete this post and prefer to comment under the same post.